# ошибка при вызове пользовательской функции

Tags: postgresql

вот текст функции:

```
create function naming_standarts.formFullObjectName(aCategory_id integer, aBaseName_id 
    integer, aNamingRule_id integer) RETURNS VARCHAR[64] AS $$
    declare
        aResultName varchar[64] := ''; /**/
        aBaseName varchar[16] := ''; /**/
        tagsForPrefix varchar[48] := ''; /**/
        currTag varchar[8] := ''; /**/
        /**/
        aBaseNameCursor cursor for select bn.basename
            from
                naming_standarts.basenames bn
            where
                bn.id = $2;
        /**/
        tagsCursor cursor for select
            cst.tag --, rto.tagorder
            from
                naming_standarts.categoryscopestags cst,
                naming_standarts.namingrules nr,
                naming_standarts.ruletagorderings rto
            where
                cst.namingcategories_id = nr.namingcategories_id
                and
                cst.namingcategories_id = rto.namingcategories_id
                and
                cst.objectscopes_id = rto.objectscopes_id
                and
                nr.id = $3
            order by rto.tagorder;

begin

    for currTag in tagsCursor loop
        tagsForPrefix := tagsForPrefix ||currTag;
    end loop;

    return tagsForPrefix;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Создалась без проблем. но выругалась при вызове:

ERROR: ОШИБКА:  ошибочный литерал массива: ""
DETAIL:  Значение массива должно начинаться с "{" или указания размерности.
CONTEXT:  функция PL/pgSQL naming_standarts.formfullobjectname(integer,integer,integer), строка 30, при инициализации локальной переменной в блоке операторов

А я нигде массивы не только не использую, но даже не определяю! Откуда ошибка и как исправить?

Comment: Хорошо бы минимизировать функцию до минимальной длины, где воспроизводится ошибка, без лишнего мусора. Трудно функцию читать и на своей БД не попробовать, т.к. используются "свои" таблицы

Answer (score 0):

При объявлении массива первичная инициализация не требуется. Если по какой то причине вы считаете, что это необходимо, вам нужно соблюдать синтаксис значений для массива `'{}'` - пустой массив, но повторю это лишнее, достаточно просто указать количество измерений, все указания размерностей игнорируются.
[Раздел справки](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/15/arrays)

ЗЫ:
Вы используете в сигнатуре функции именованные аргументы, используйте их так же и в теле функции это упрощает чтение кода, особенно в больших листингах.

Answer (score 0):

> А я нигде массивы не только не использую, но даже не определяю!
>
> ```
> declare
>     aResultName varchar[64] := ''; /**/
>     aBaseName varchar[16] := ''; /**/
>     tagsForPrefix varchar[48] := ''; /**/
>     currTag varchar[8] := ''; /**/
> ```

Как же не используете, когда вот сразу в начале листинга объявлено 4 массива?

Я могу, конечно, попробовать догадаться, что подразумевалось `varchar(64)` вместо `varchar[64]`, но база угадывать не будет, раз вы сказали что это массив из 64 элементов - хранимка объявит массив.